# Hide tab if no posts are found in loop

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have a customised wordpress search page that groups the result into the custom post type header.

This works but it still shows the post type if there are no posts in it.

What can I do to check to see if the section has posts, and if not, hide the section.

Note: if( !empty ( $hasposts ) ) currently returns FULL for each check as the post types have posts, but they are not part of the search results.

```
<?php       
if( have_posts() ){
    //Define post types:
    $types = array('post', 'promo_offers', 'product_manuals', 'support_posts','product');
    foreach( $types as $type ){

        // RETURN EMPTY IF THE RESLUTS FOR THE POST TYPE IS EMPTY
        $hasposts = have_posts($type);
        if( !empty ( $hasposts ) ) { echo '<div>FULL!</div>';} else {echo '<div>EMPTY!</div>';}

        //BELOW CODE WORKS AS INTENDED
        echo 'your container opens here for ' . $type;
        echo '<ul>';
        while( have_posts() ){
            the_post();        
            if( $type == get_post_type() ){
                echo '<li>';
                the_title();
                echo '</li>';
            }
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        rewind_posts();
        echo 'your container closes here for ' . $type;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: where you are searching do you mean this line  if( $type == get_post_type() ){ ?

Comment: I've never seen have_posts() take a parameter. In fact, the words `This function does not accept any parameters.` can be found on the have_posts() page: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/have_posts

Comment: How are you defining "type"? Is it a category? A tag? A custom post_type?

Comment: @dipmala This is on the search.php page template, so the search has already been done and the posts on the page are a result of the search

Comment: $type is the post type

Answer (score 0):

So my understanding is that have_posts() doesn't take parameters, and actually I'm curious about what happens when you call

```
$hasposts = have_posts($type);
```

Your function is looping through all posts multiple times, but only displaying those posts that have the type of $type. The point is that have_posts() returns true every time because it's referring to all posts, not just of the specified type.

So I think that what you need is to make a separate query for each type, like so:

```
foreach( $types as $type ) {
    query_posts("post_type=$type");

    while (have_posts() ) {
         //now this should only happen if the specific type has posts in it...
    }
}
```